# to_sql to mysql insert error

Tags: mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm using a mysql server.

Error in insert data into mysql server with to_sql function.

my table(dataframe)

```
        a       b               c           d           e   f   
   0    465894  2017000002(01)  65.9807     93.3036     34  4   
   1    465894  2017000002(02)  075.5061A   104.3414    59  7       
   2    465894  2017000002(03)  075.8986B   106.0494    29  3       
   3    465894  2017000002(04)  084.9732    114.8906    34  4

   >> table.dtypes
      a     int64
      b     object
      c     object
      d     float64
      e     int64
      f     int64
      dtype: object


   >> table.to_sql(
                  'table_name',
                   engine,
                   if_exists='append',
                   index=False
                   )
```

Column (a,b,d,e,f) successfully inserted.

> but only "c:" column error
>
> error message : numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'translate
>
> I need to convert a column data to a number and delete the character.
>
> but I want to insert it as a character type

How can you solve the problem?

thankyou~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `c` is a column of mixed dtypes. I don't think mysql provides support for that, so you can just convert the entire thing to a string, and it should work:

```
df['c'] = df['c'].astype(str)
```

Comment: `df[['b','c']] = df[['b','c']].astype(str)` if I am not mistaken

Comment: @joaoavf maybe... I singled out C because that's the column the error was thrown on :)

Comment: @coldspeed  oh.. thankyou  I tried table ['c']. astype (str), but that was not it. //   df['c'].astype(str)  ==> df['c'] = df['c'].astype(str)